# Converting CSV file to .json file in a specific format using python

Tags: python, json

I have the below input.csv file and I'm having trouble in converting it to a .json file.
Below is the `input.csv` file that I have which I want to convert it into .json file. The Text field is in `Sinhala Language`

> Date,Text,Category
> 2021-07-28,"['ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව']",Sports
> 2021-07-28,"['ඊයේ', 'ඊයේ']",Sports
> 2021-07-29,"['ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව']",Sports
> 2021-07-29,"['ඊයේ', 'ඊයේ', 'ඊයේ', 'ඊයේ']",Sports
> 2021-08-01,"['ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව']",Sports

The .json format that I want to have is as of below

```
[
{
    "category":"Sports",
    "date":"2021-07-28",
    "data": ['ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව']
},
{
    "category":"Sports",
    "date":"2021-07-28",
    "data": ['ඊයේ', 'ඊයේ']
},
{
    "category":"Sports",
    "date":"2021-07-29",
    "data": ['ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව']
},
{
    "category":"Sports",
    "date":"2021-07-29",
    "data": ['ඊයේ', 'ඊයේ', 'ඊයේ', 'ඊයේ']
},
{
    "category":"Sports",
    "date":"2021-08-01",
    "data": ['ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව', 'ලංකාව']
}
]
```

Below is how I tried, since this is of Sinhala Language, values are show in this format `\u0d8a\u0dba\u0dda`, which is another thing that I'm struggling to sort out. And the json format is also wrong that I expect it to be.

```
import csv
import json


def toJson():
    csvfile = open('outputS.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

    fieldnames = ("date", "text", "category")
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
    out = json.dumps([row for row in reader])
    jsonfile.write(out)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    toJson()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ensure_ascii=False` when doing `json.dumps`:

```
out = json.dumps([row for row in reader], ensure_ascii=False)
```

#### Other notes:

- Since the first row of the csv contains the column names, you should either skip this first row, or let `csv.DictReader` use the first row as the column names automatically by not passing explicit values to `fieldnames`.
- It's very bad practice to use `open` and then not close it.
  To make things easier you can use a `with` statement.
- The second column of the csv file will be treated as a string and not as a list of strings unless you specifically parse it as such (you can use `literal_eval` from the `ast` module for this).
- You can use `json.dump` instead of `json.dumps` to write directly to the file.

With this, you can rewrite your function to:

```
def toJson():
    with (open('delete.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile,
        open('file.json', 'w') as jsonfile):

        fieldnames = ("date", "text", "category")
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
        next(reader)  # skip header row

        json.dump([row for row in reader], jsonfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read your CSV using pandas   `# using pd.read_csv()`
2. use to_dict function with orient option set to records

   `df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file_name.csv')`

   `df.to_dict(orient='records')`